# Fragments always go through onAttach to onDestroyView, instead of onCreateView to onDestroyView

Tags: java, android, fragment, lifecycle

I am using 4 fragments in 1 activity. The navigation is done via NavDrawer. Every time I navigate through the fragments, each fragment goes through the following methods:
onAttach() to onDestroyView()
I was expecting them to go through these once and then go through onCreateView() to onDestroyView() but this is not happening.
I would like to initialize certain things only once in onCreate() but now I cannot.
Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: Hi @Anthony, it really depends on your implementation. Maybe you "kill" the latest active fragment whenever you navigate from it. It's hard to tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for the reply.
I found the problem. I was creating a new fragment in the nav drawers itemselect. To solve it I created an instance of each fragment in main activity and just set this to current fragment instead of creating a new one.

Thanks again

Comment: You will run into the same problems as this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753099/app-crash-after-activity-has-been-killed-in-background/55754360#55754360