# View pager fragments removing

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My activity should handle portrait and landscape layouts in different ways: if layout is portrait, then in should use `ViewPager` with two fragments. If layout is landscape, then it should just divide screen on two parts and locate two fragments there. The problem is that when I switch from portrait to landscape, viewpager's fragments are not removed and `onCreateView()` is called for them.

Calling removing fragments with FragmentTransaction does nothing.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.weather_layout, new CurrentWeatherFragment(), "current");
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.forecast_layout, new ForecastFragment(), "forecast");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        else {
            ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
            WeatherPageAdapter weatherPageAdapter = new WeatherPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPager.setAdapter(weatherPageAdapter);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new WeatherPageChangedListener());
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewModel.getViewPagerPosition(), false);
        }
    }
```

```java
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import com.example.android.myapplication.ui.fragments.CurrentWeatherFragment;
import com.example.android.myapplication.ui.fragments.ForecastFragment;

public class WeatherPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static final int pageNumber = 2;

    public WeatherPageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return new CurrentWeatherFragment();
        }
        else {
            return new ForecastFragment();
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="7"
    android:columnCount="2"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="7"
    android:columnCount="2"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/weather_layout">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/forecast_layout">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add code for your WeatherAdapter?

Comment: @Froyo added adapter and xmls

Comment: What do you mean by `viewpager's fragments are not removed and onCreateView() is called for them`? The fragments are same (class) in landscape and portrait. How do you check viewpager fragments are not removed?

Comment: @Froyo, I can check it by tag. View pager's fragments have switcher tag. And if i check quantity of fragments before and after calling remove transaction, they are equal

Answer (score 0):

In your earlier code, Do the following modification:

```
private ViewPager viewPager;
private WeatherPageAdapter weatherPageAdapter;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        changeViewAsPerOrientation(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
    }

private void changeViewAsPerOrientation(Configuration newConfig) {
      for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        }
      if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.weather_layout, new CurrentWeatherFragment(), "current");
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.forecast_layout, new ForecastFragment(), "forecast");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
      }
      else {
         if(viewPager == null || weatherPageAdapter == null) {
          viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
          weatherPageAdapter = new  WeatherPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
          viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new WeatherPageChangedListener());
        } else {
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewModel.getViewPagerPosition(), false);
      }
    }

@Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    changeViewAsPerOrientation(newConfig);
  }
```

Comment: Where should I call that two rows?

Comment: then I should add ViewPager in both, portrait and landscape, xml layouts?

Comment: Sorry. But if i call   ```viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new WeatherPageChangedListener());``` in landscape mode, then I get ```NullPointerException``` because I do not have it in landscape XML layout. Thus I ask about adding it there.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for that. I thought you have a single layout. I have now modified the code. please try again.

Comment: This ViewPagerAdapter will break after process death (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046773/singleton-object-becomes-null-after-app-is-resumed/49107399#49107399), the fragments you provide from outside will NEVER be used, and the fragments in `pageList` and `forecastFragment` and `currentWeatherFragment` will NOT be the same instance as what is on the screen. Please don't get people to use this, because it is wrong and it will eventually break (see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753099/app-crash-after-activity-has-been-killed-in-background/55754360#55754360)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you for your info. I have updated the answer. Let me know if it's the correct way.

Comment: I guess that would technically work, but it will lose view state across orientation changes. You would also need to do some sort of trickery, similar to https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/blob/8edd0c80e2887c429fc2dede5f3c5607a7e2a47d/simple-stack-flow-masterdetail-fragments/src/main/java/com/example/stackmasterdetailfrag/MasterDetailFragmentStateChanger.java#L114-L117 .

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes, you are right. It won't maintain the view state. But then I might have to write the whole application code here. 

Comment: Fragments are pain XD

Comment: Technically that downvote went for the `ViewPagerAdapter(List<Fragment` because that's a very nasty source of bugs. As it is no longer part of the answer, I will retract it

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks again for informing about it. I was totally unaware of that.  Кирилл Волков Try this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui It may help.

Comment: Code doesn't work(( FragmentTransactipn doesn't remove view pager's fragments